# add a static variable and a non static variable together in java

Tags: java, oop, static

Can we add a static variable and a non static variable together in java?
For example,

```
class Evolve{
    static int i = 1;
    static int j = 2;
    int x = 3;
    static int y = 6;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(i + j);
        System.out.println(x + i);
        System.out.println(i + y);
        System.out.println(x + j);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not until you initialize an instance of Evolve and refer to it as

```
this.i
```

or like this

```
Evolve evolve = new Evolve();
System.out.println(evolve.i + Evolve.j);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the *non-static* (or *instance*) variable `x` is not accessible in the static context of the `main` method.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the non static to be in an instance, then you can add them using `Evolve.i + this.x`

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to do with static/non-static about whether you can add it or not.

It is simply how you should access static and non-static (instance) variable.

Answer (score 1):

Since **x** is an instance variable, you need an instance of the Evolve object...

```
public static void main(String args[]){
  Evolve ev = new Evolve();
  System.out.println(Evolve.i + Evolve.j);
  System.out.println(ev.x + Evolve.i);
  System.out.println(Evolve.i + Evolve.y);
  System.out.println(ev.x + Evolve.j);
}
```